# Pipelining vs. partial application for API design

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pipeline

In F#, many functions that take sequences have the sequence as the last parameter to support pipelining.

When designing an API, I can follow that trend, as in this simple state machine example:

```
type Transition =
    { CurrentState : string; TriggeringEvent : string; NewState : string }

let getNewState currentState triggeringEvent transitions =
    let isMatch t =
        t.CurrentState = currentState
        && t.TriggeringEvent = triggeringEvent
    match transitions |> Seq.tryFind isMatch with
    | Some transition -> Some(transition.NewState)
    | None -> None

let myTransitions =
    [ { CurrentState = "A"; TriggeringEvent = "one"; NewState = "B" };
      { CurrentState = "B"; TriggeringEvent = "two"; NewState = "A" } ]

let result = myTransitions |> getNewState "A" "one"

printfn "%A" result
```

Here `getNewState` has signature:

```
(string -> string -> seq<Transition> -> string option)
```

which supports pipelining:

```
myTransitions |> getNewState "A" "one"
```

But in some cases, the sequence is constant while the other arguments vary. In the state machine example, the transition table (`transitions`) will be fixed for a given state machine. `getNewState` will be called multiple times with different states and events. If the sequence were the *first* parameter, callers could use partial application:

```
let getNewState transitions currentState triggeringEvent =
    // body same as before

let stateMachine = getNewState myTransitions

let result1 = stateMachine "A" "one"
let result2 = stateMachine "B" "two"

printfn "%A" result1
printfn "%A" result2
```

Now `getNewState` has signature:

```
(seq<Transition> -> string -> string -> string option)
```

and `stateMachine` has signature:

```
(string -> string -> string option)
```

How can I design an API to support both pipelining and partial application, at the caller's option?

Comment: Your `getNewState` is a let-bound function, so I don't think there is an easy solution to what you are seeking.  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx .)  One solution might be to define a new type--say, a record--for the argument to `getNewState`, so that regardless of what is varying, you can build a new record and pipe it to `getNewState`.  Or you can wait for either Petricek or Pappas to provide an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipelining uses partial application, it is just another way to call a function by specifying the parameter first and then the function.

`myTransitions |> getNewState "A" "one"`

Here `getNewState` is first partially applied to get a function with one param and then that function is called with myTransitions.

The way to have a function that can have different parameter order but the function name still remains same is using method overloading i.e have a type with static methods but then you loose the implicit partial application because methods takes parameters as a single tuple.

It would be better to stick with one signature and the caller can easily create another function which has different parameter order as required. For example in your second code example you can use the first example's `getNewState` as:

`let stateMachine a b = getNewState a b myTransitions`

Answer (score 2):

Why would the transitions need to vary don't they form the very definition of your state machine?

In any case, if you feel the urge that the transitions be at the last place but you still want partially apply, you could always make a function that does just that:

```
let getNewState currentState triggeringEvent transitions = 
    // your definition from above
let createStateMachine transitions currentState triggeringEvent =
    getNewState currentState triggeringEvent transitions)
```

or you could make a general `rotateArgs` function and use it to define your special signature something like this:

```
let rotateArgs f z x y = f x y z
let createStateMachine = rotateArgs getNewState
```

(Or the caller can always do it for himself in case you are missing some signature they need)

Comment: The transitions should not need to vary; as you say, they define the state machine.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend *not* to define `transistions` to be the last parameter, just as Daniel said. A function that, given a transition table, generates a state machine seems to make more sense (e.g. Daniel's `createStateMachine`).